# How to minimise the difference between two time-shifted vectors in R

Tags: r, optimization

I have two data sets with x and y observations that represent the same data, but one of them is slightly shifted in x. In addition, the y values can differ slightly.

Example:

```
library(Hmisc)
x_a <- c(-10:10)
y_a <- (x_a^2) + 4

y_b <- jitter(x_a^2 + 2, 20)
x_b <-  Lag(x_a, 2)
plot(x_b, y_b)
points(x_a, y_a, pch = 5)
```

How can I find the optimal "shift value" for x that minimises the difference between the two data sets (in this case 2)?

Comment: could you simply use `?optimize`?

Comment: if you need to shift in both directions you can use `?optim` instead